# how to remove full words not subwords in javascript

Tags: javascript

In this example I just want to remove the word "a" not letter a in all words but regex doesn't seem to work.

```
var str = "A brown fox always jumps over the orange apple in a weird way"; 
var res = str.replace(/a/g, "");
```

//result is brown fox lwys jumps over the ornge pple in a weird wy
   //but i'd just like brown fox always jumps over the orange apple in weird way

I guess I could look for the index of the word a and cut it out but is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to find only the word "a".

For example;

```
var str = "A brown fox always jumps over the orange apple in a weird way"; 
var res = str.replace(/\ba\b/g, "");
```

Comment: oooo  thanks word boundaries work, need a few more mins to accept

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b` to check for word boundaries. Also use `i` switch to make case insensitive match.

Try

```js
var str = "A brown fox always jumps over the orange apple in a weird way"; 
console.log(str.replace(/\ba\b/ig, "").trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var res = (str.charAt(0));
```

With this, you select the first character of the string. Is that what you want ?